# Read content of excel file from server in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is my api request to read the excel file -

```
function getExportContents(exportId) {
    return api.req(path + exportId, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
      },
      json: true
    });
  }

let exportFileContent=await this.getExportContents('5916');
  console.log(exportFileContent);
```

**Output**

> PK��R_rels/.rels���J1��}�0�n�D�i/E�M�>����a7����}{�u邂�af���$���G�F)�l�ˮ������TGd�B���F����>fU !�D���v�1W)�N�ɣ�2�:��%���[��3`U'g ���SKb`�;��y�
> �4.�~��M�[:�}��J�l���KƱ}L\V1����I(8r�X(I_���tsE�r��9-���$�P�:7�?��~�PK�y/�PPK��R[Content_Types].xml�SMO1��+6��m��1���G%@mgن~�S���MDL0�S;yo�{3i�Ӎ����6�CV�WA�h�����ef鵴�Cö�l:���XQ�ǆu9�;!Pu�$��҆�d�2-D�j)
> �������s��#�h����~���Q2S0���@��+���`g"^�U�R� D(2q��ag�K�-'
> �

I want this in readable format to validate the content. How can I parse this ?

Comment: Before reading, can your excel file be converted to another format, like CSV?

Comment: Yes. But how will I convert it ..I am reading the content from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lib to parse the data. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx could help you.